# Angular Serving Assets as MIME ('text/html')

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Whenever we release a new version of our Angular App, the page will not load for users unless they clear their cache. It just keeps our loader spinning forever and is stuck on `index.html`.

In the chrome console there is an error saying that *`styles.css-hash`* has a MIME type of ('text/html') and that it is not a supported stylesheet MIME type. Note that I have also seen this happen with javascript files, including the *`main.js-hash`* from angular.

If we `shift-click refresh` or `ctrl F5` to clear cache it loads the new *`styles.css-newhash`* and the page will load.

I have the stylesheet referenced in the `angular.json` (we are using angular 7) and not in the index.html.

Note most other questions similar to this suggest changing to relative pathing in the `angular.json` or to not reference the linked files in the `index.html` and to instead reference them in the `angular-cli.json` or the `angular.json`. Neither of these solutions worked.

We are not using the angular service worker.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the webserver, not Angular. Since the #hash has changed, the previous file does not exist anymore.

The webserver is most likely showing a `Page not found` also known as `404` page, which has a mime of `text/html`, since it's a webpage.

You need to clear the cache on cache services like Cloudfront / Fastly / Varnish etc. if you have any.

You could also add `no-cache`headers to the page, but this is not recommended, it's better to set a lesser cache time than standard, depending on your release / update frequency.

You should really remove the #hash part from production files, to not have this problem on production servers.
Then the cached files will work until they are cleared, and the new ones will kick in.

Comment: Thats awesome, mostly if you have error pages configured on CloudFront for 403/404 etc , requesting for css is now returning a html file and browser throws these errors.

Comment: We are using IIS currently and nothing with CloudFlare etc. I can do the build like:  ng build --prod --outputHashing=none to have it not show the hashes at the end, and then we can turn down the time for the cache to expire in IIS. I'm just perplexed because this was not happening before. Could it be something to do with our base href in index.html or that we switched to use specific (not relative) pathing in our import statements in angular?

Comment: We're going to try this solution then see if this works for tomorrow morning. It's not the best solution, but we're going to try it. I really would like to know why it was working before, and now it's not. I'm not 100% certain it's web server related. I think it could be angular configuration related.

Comment: Open the urls that is reporting `the text/html` and see if it's a `Page not found` or if it's really a css | js file, easiest way to find out. Angular can't really change a MIME like a web server can.

Comment: So this solution to remove the hash from the files works. And we added back in the service worker and it seems to be going well. --outputHashing=none is to remove hashes.  I still would like a solution where hashing is used though.

Comment: Then you basically need to remove caching of the files on that page.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned it happens sometimes with your css and sometimes with your js files.

It might be that it's a problem with how your server is configured and your index.html file is being cached. On deploying a new version, you might be getting the old index.html file(unless user clears cache), and hence fetching the previous hash versions of css/js files, which of course are not there anymore.

So the web server responds with 404 and some Not Found content html type.